# please hlep me while Packet tracer run floating point

Tags: root, packet-analyzer

Starting Packet Tracer 7.2.2
/usr/local/bin/packettracer: line 8: 12865 Floating point exception(core dumped) ./PacketTracer7 "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: How did you install this Packet Tracer?

Comment: Suggest : Update to "Packet Tracer 7.3.0..." https://www.packettracernetwork.com/download/download-packet-tracer.html >>> PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)